# How to get text from a section of a website using Selenium in Python 3

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was wondering how I can pull text from a website using Selenium and Python 3. I don't know what the text is, so I can't just look for the sentence and copy it. Here is an example screenshot: [Example Problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0qS0.png) Know in this scenario I am looking for the small amount of text right after the 1. but it is represented by just ::header, so I am having trouble grabbing it. Any ideas? Thanks! Also the website I am pulling from is [Quia.](https://quia.com)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the html code in question.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan I think [this](https://imgur.com/a/Y0DOjYX) is what you meant.

Comment: print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='quia_standard']").get_attribute("innerHTML").splitlines()[0]) try this

Comment: @ArundeepChohan Almost but I got this: `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[@class='quia_standard']"}`

Comment: Can you check if it's in any iframes/

Comment: I'm so sorry I'm super new to this but do I just search for anything called "iframe" in inspect element or something?

Comment: Pretty much just do that

Comment: @ArundeepChohan This is the only [thing](https://imgur.com/a/QwAUyVS) I found

Comment: If the element is inside it then you'll have to switch to the frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer directly because this web example is behind login. Broadly speaking you may use xpath expressions which needs information about xml/html tree(In example available under F12 button on PC keyboard when using Chrome or Firefox. „Inspect” from contex mouse menu is also the way).
Example on login page of same server to get welcome text:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def s_obj(sel_drv, xph):
    return sel_drv.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = f"{xph}")

def s_text(sel_drv, xph):
    els = s_obj(sel_drv, xph)
    return '; '.join(el.text.replace('\n', '; ')\
        for el in els).strip(';').strip() if els else ''

test_url = "https://www.quia.com/web"

sel_drv = webdriver.Chrome()
sel_drv.get(test_url)
bs_xph = "//*/table/tbody/tr/td[@colspan=\"5\"]/h1[@class=\"home\"]"
expected_txt = s_text(sel_drv, f"{bs_xph}[1]")
print(expected_txt)
sel_drv.quit()
```

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to this type of stuff and am having trouble finding out how xpath and such works, can you give me an idea of how to generate this path to get the text? I can follow you up to the "[@colspan=\"5\"]", thanks for your help! And if you know any resources that would stop me from wasting your time, please let me know!

Comment: You just need to navigate the html tree to the desired branch. The expressions in square brackets help identify them, and performing action is just a search. The `[1]` at the end means selecting second element of list(first one is more common or empty, I do not remember at the moment).
You can most simply use just `sel_drv.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value = f"{xph}")`, my `s_obj` and `s_text` functions are the usual wrappers, whereby `s_text` in the case no sensible content returns `''` instead of the tricky, not usable data.